Axe-murdering ghost mother in a cabin
I've been trying to find this movie for a while. This is what I remember for the movie - at the beginning some friends go camping in the woods and one guy spots a girl. They later they go to her cabin and start kissing and then her mom comes in and kills the guy with an axe. The theme of the story is that they where actually spirits who were repeating a crime that happened to them years ago. 

Do you remember anything else that could help identify the movie? The details you gave are quite vague. Rough idea of the year or decade? High-budget, low-budget, B-movie? American, British, other?

Sounds vaguely similar to "The House Where Evil Dwells".

Sounds like the plot of the low-budget horror film Scar from 2005: Two young guys called Tom and Zack hike in the woods and come across a cabin and a cute blonde. She flirts with Zack, he goes in and they make out, when suddenly her mother appears and attacks him with an axe. A year later, Tom and Zack's ex-girlfriend go back to the cabin to find out what happened to Zack. Turns out the blonde and her mom are ghosts who repeat the same scenario with whatever guy they come across. Here's the trailer:



